# Как работает SELECT CONVERT (DECIMAL..?

Tags: sql

На собеседовании попросили объяснить результаты трёх запросов:

```
SELECT 2/3;
SELECT CONVERT (DECIMAL (18,6))2/3;
SELECT CONVERT (DECIMAL (18,6),2)/3;
```

Первый запрос округляет значение до нуля, ладно.
Почему второй здесь нерешаем?
Почему в третьем выдаёт значение восьми шестёрок после нуля?

Comment: В вопросах по SQL всегда указывайте СУБД. Желательно и в теге (чтобы специалисты по конкретной СУБД с большей вероятностью увидели ваш вопрос), и в вопросе, причем с версией, потому что, в разных версиях поведение может отличаться.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос (вернее, ответ на него) абсолютно зависит от конкретной DBMS.

Например, в MySQL будут получены следующие значения (после устранения синтаксических погрешностей, конечно):

```
mysql> SELECT 2/3;
+--------+
| 2/3    |
+--------+
| 0.6667 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONVERT (2/3, DECIMAL (18,6));
+-------------------------------+
| CONVERT (2/3, DECIMAL (18,6)) |
+-------------------------------+
|                      0.666667 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONVERT (2, DECIMAL (18,6))/3;
+-------------------------------+
| CONVERT (2, DECIMAL (18,6))/3 |
+-------------------------------+
|                  0.6666666667 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Почему второй здесь нерешаем?

Потому что `CONVERT` это функция с двумя параметрами.

> Почему в третьем выдаёт значение восьми шестёрок после нуля?

Восемь цифр после запятой - представление `DECIMAL(20,8)`, получающегося от деления `DECIMAL(18,6)` и целого.

Сравните

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,6), 2.0/3); -> 0.666666
```

и

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,6),2)/3 as Value, 
  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,6),2)/3, 'BaseType') as Type, 
  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,6),2)/3, 'Precision') as Precision, 
  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,6),2)/3, 'Scale') as Scale;

-> 

0.66666666  decimal  20  8
```

Comment: Спасибо, значит во втором запросе я ошибся со скобками SELECT CONVERT (DECIMAL (18,6)2/3); и решением будет 0,000000.

Comment: @vienya да. еще нужна запятая между параметрами - типом и значением